# Add commands after custom LaTeX split window view

Tags: latex, window, emacsclient

I use

```lisp
(setq TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Emacs" "emacsclient -e '(split-window-horizontally 88) 'emacsclient -e '(other-window 1)'; emacsclient %o;"))))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection (quote (((output-dvi style-pstricks) "dvips and gv") (output-dvi "xdvi") (output-html "xdg-open") (output-pdf "Emacs"))))
```

to view the pdf files in a split window.

I would like to extend the first command a little bit (right now it splits the window, changes to the other window and opens the pdf file there)

- The split command leaves the new (pdf) buffer active, but I would like to have the original one active.
- I would like to sync the position in the source file with the pdf file.

I can do this by hand by calling `other window` and `pdf-sync-forward-search` right after the latex view command, but I am sure this can be done automatically.

I tried to add `emacsclient -e '(other-window 1)'`, but it looks like I don't quite understand how the commands work.